# GStreamer plays video with wrong resolution when I use vaapisink in pipeline

Tags: video, gstreamer, wayland

I try to play video using gstreamer. There are two possiple output sinks to use: `waylandsink` and `vaapisink`. When I play video with `waylandsink`, everything is fine. When I try to play it with `vaapisink`, it is played with wrong resolution (part of the screen is empty).

When I play video with the following pipeline, it is OK

```
gst-launch 1.0 filesrc location=test.mkv ! video/x-raw ! decodebin3 ! waylandsink
```

This pipeline does not work properly. When I change resolution parameters, they are ignored.

```
gst-launch 1.0 filesrc location=test.mkv ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! decodebin3 ! vaapisink
```

What can be the reason? Does vaapisink need some additional information about screen resolution? Any tips, even keywords for googling, are appreciated.